# Executing existing parametrised BigQuery view from bq cmd tool

Tags: view, google-bigquery, prepared-statement

How to execute the existing BigQuery [parametrized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) with passing parameters (@param) without sending the view query as well?

I would like to execute existing view with placeholders for my custom parameters.

My minimalistic view saved in BigQuery in `project.dataset.view`:

```
select * from `project.dataset.table`  
where column = @x
```

My `bq` cmd looks like:

```
bq --location=EU query --use_legacy_sql=False \
--parameter='x:INT64:100' \
--destination_table="dev.view_result" "[HERE IS THE SAME VIEW COPIED]"
```

Like that I am not executing the existing view, I am creating a new select query (new view).

Is it possible to call it somehow like:

```
bq --location=EU query --use_legacy_sql=False \
--parameter='x:INT64:100' \
--destination_table="dataset.view_result"
--view=[VIEW_URL like dataset.view]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views with parameters are not supported in BigQuery yet - see related[`feature request`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905221)

Comment: But I guess for now it is okay to save ````select * from project.dataset.table````  as myview in bigquery dataset and then just execute ```select * from myview where column = 5``` (tableau). The filter will be pushed down to the first select statement.

Comment: sure. should work. just have in mind  - because of `SELECT *` the whole table scan will be taking place

Comment: okay, but if you use ```select * from table``` and save that in view in BQ, and then you query the view with ```select * from view where partitioning_ts_or_date_field = ...``` then the filter will be pushed immediately to the first select statement and you won't scan the whole table, because only that one day will be scanned. This is the workaround for clients (tableau) to specify partitioning without having to copy/paste the code from the bigquery view. Instead, they reuse the view's code and just define partitioning.